# Checking if a string starts and ends with number characters using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying:

```java
String string = "123456";    
if(string.startsWith("[0-9]") && string.endsWith("[0-9]")){
    //code
}
```

And the `if` clause is never called.

Comment: What led you to believe it's a regex argument?

Comment: Where is the variable name?

Comment: Is it just me or is there no question in the post?

Comment: We have assumed the missing last word is: "Why?"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't use a regex:

```
Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0)) && 
                              Character.isDigit(string.charAt(string.length()-1))
```

(see [`Character.isDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29))

Comment: I think that this is the more faster way.

Comment: I agree, no regex needed.

Comment: @MattSmith Are you sure it's from this line? There are no cases where this should cause an `IllegalStateException`. Try checking the surrounding code.

Answer (score 9):

The methods `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` in class `String` accept only String, not a regex.

Comment: Very true, but as it stands this is more of comment than an answer. How would you suggest they "...[check] if a string starts and ends with number characters."?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `matches` method on `String` thusly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("123456".matches("^\\d.*?\\d$"));
    System.out.println("123456A".matches("^\\d.*?\\d$"));
    System.out.println("A123456".matches("^\\d.*?\\d$"));
    System.out.println("A123456A".matches("^\\d.*?\\d$"));
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
false
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I want to use the same concept in javascript, however when I use `^\\d.*?\\d$` for a string, it does not work. For string `3rd` it should give `false` and for strings `3` or `3(white spaces)` the output should be `true`. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
String string = "123test123";
if(string.matches("\\d.*\\d"))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @ProgramFOX You actually don't need the anchors with `matches()`.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the code snippet.

```
String variableString = "012testString";
Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0)) && variableString.Any(c => char.IsUpper(c));
```